# Display specific data from array with id

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I would like to display data from an Vuex store array like in this example,

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{this.$store.state.data.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{this.$store.state.data.text}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

but with an id which specifies from which item in the array i would get it.

Is it possible or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **computed** property :

```
 <template>
     <div>
        <h1>{{getTitle}}</h1>
        <p>{{getText}}</p>
     </div>
   </template>
<script>
export default {
    computed:{
        getTitle(){
            return this.$store.state.data.find(item => item.id === YOUR_ID).title
        },
        getText(){
            return this.$store.state.data.find(item => item.id === YOUR_ID).text
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with js filter and the vue.js computed property to filter the table and get only the specific values you want based on the id. here's an example:

```
 <template>
     <div>
        <h1>{{mydata.data_title}}</h1>
        <p>{{mydata.data_description}}</p>
     </div>
   </template>
<script>
export default {
    computed:{
        mydata(){
            return {
             data_title: this.$store.state.data.filter(x=> x.id === 1).title,
             data_description: this.$store.state.data.filter(x=> x.id === 1).text
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>
```